# How to manage and analyse user feedback

Tags: info-visualisation, user-feedback, data-analysis

We have several user-feedback-channels: iOS and Android store reviews, web forms, support records.

1. Is there a tool that can help merge all this feedback in one place?
2. What is the best way to process this data? We want to add tags to all this reviews and comments, may be there is a tool that will do it automatically?

Comment: This is a huge question that touches data engineering, data science, tech stacks, etc. which happens to be my field but isn't a UI/UX question :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it relates to collecting and analyzing data sets, not UI/UX

Comment: @J.Dimeo Why not? Part of the job as a UX designer is to collect and evaluate feedback. So why should it not be an interesting topic on how to collect it from various sources?

Comment: I guess I interpreted it to be about implementation and technology, not generally applicable guidelines. But I didn't downvote it in case people disagree!

Comment: @J.Dimeo, yeah, you're right, it's a huge question, if you're looking from this point of view. I'll formulate question more clear next time :) Right now, my main problem is to feedback loop to gain actionable insights from users and provide them to product team.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a R Package to gather data from Ios ( https://datascienceplus.com/analysing-ios-app-store-itunes-reviews-in-r/ ), and you can easily access it by download on Google ( https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230?hl=en ). For the web forms and support thing, download csv and use it to merge it on R ( https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html )

Well, it depends on what you're looking for.
Qualitative datas can be analyzed through what people say about you or your products (using packages on R)
Quantitatives analysis can be made through basic R packages and functions.

I can't be more precise, mainly because I don't know what's your question :
Do you want to have a broad view of what you're doing? On how your support is received by your users?

Comment: Thank you for answer! I'll try this R package to gather all our reviews together

About our question: 
It's only a hypothesis, but we think that reviews should help us find, validate and prioritize user needs and product growth points. 
For example, we want to be able to see all reviews where user asks us about certain feature (or tells us about some problem).
So, you can say, that we want have a broad view on what users tell us about.

The next step is to get their emails and contact them to dig into their need (problem that they talk about).

I hope that adds clarity to my question

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification, I have a better understanding of your needs. So yeah, I think R should do the job. Don't hesitate to "class" reviews depending on the subject to help you analyze it maybe!
Good luck on that User Research, always hard to find people! =)